# How to refresh the OAUTH2 BOX token in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm using the BOX SDK to access box.com items programatically. SDK gives me the new pair of tokens whenever current access token is expired for a single thread request.

My question is how to 'refresh' the access token in multithreaded application (website). Making the OAuthDataController.doRefresh to synchronized will solve my problem? Or do i need to put some additional logic.

P.s I've helper class to load and archive the tokens in/from txt file.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a multi-threaded app, then you need to synchronize on the refresh block.

In java, the classic way to do this is by using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).   Other languages allow similar mechanisms to coordinate an operation that needs to be coordinated across multiple threads.